# update fusion table from google maps API

Tags: google-maps, google-fusion-tables

I've linked a fusion table with google maps API and each point within my map has html code for the balloon to display attributes from the fusion table.

What I'd like to do is allow a user to update information in the fusion table directly from within the balloon after clicking a placemark. Say there are three attributes that could be updated: Type, Condition, and Visibility.

I can't seem to find any instructions on how to do this but I imagine it should be possible... has anyone done something like this? Essentially I'd like to find a way to get the Fusion Table "edit row" feature embedded in the balloon.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can always use an UPDATE query to update the data in the Google Fusion Table through front end which is your map.

```
UPDATE <table_id>
SET <column_name> = <value> {, <column_name> = <value> }*
WHERE ROWID = <row_id>
```

This is the pseudo code for the to update the attributes in your table.
For more information regarding updating the coordinates please refer to the following document.
https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/sql-reference#updateRow

Comment: Yes, I understand that code, so I'd want to put a dropdown list in a balloon that passes a value to the Update query where ROWID would be equal to whatever row that placemark is from. Say there was a column named "Visibility" and I wanted to change the value from 'Clear' to 'Obstructed' I would need, somewhere:
1. <Select id="Visibility"> for dropdown list
2. Some function to grab the value
3. Some function to pass the value to an update query using the Fusion API and reference the right row based on the placemark currently being viewed
4. A prompt letting the user know it was successful?